# My first sql trigger in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, triggers, using

I tried to execute the following code when I ran into a wierd error.
I hope you guys can help me out here :)

```
CREATE TRIGGER Vlucht_Duurtussenstop
   ON  dbo.Vlucht
   AFTER UPDATE,INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
 IF (new.Duurtussenstop <> old.Duurtussenstop)
    BEGIN
      EXECUTE dbo.testprocudure1
         @p_vluchtDuurtussenstop = Duurtussenstop
    END
END
GO
```

Gives

```
[15:50:03] Gert-Jan Bos: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near ' '.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
Incorrect syntax near ' '.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
Incorrect syntax near ' '.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server doesn't have `new` and `old`. It has `inserted` and `deleted` pseudo-tables, but these may contain multiple rows if the original statement affected multiple rows.

It would also be unclear, from your usage, whether `testprocudure1` is being called with the old value or the new value, so I can't re-write your query at this time.

---

Ideally, the body of the `testprocudure1` could be expanded out in the trigger, to avoid having to use a cursor - but to find the rows that you're interested in, the query would resemble:

```
SELECT i.Duurtussenstop,d.Duurtussenstop
FROM
    inserted i
        join
    deleted d
        on
             i.Col1 = d.Col1 and
             i.Col2 = d.Col2
```

where I assume the primary key on the table is (`Col1`,`Col2`)

Comment: Awesome! Thx for your reply however, my teacher gave me this example code :


CREATE TRIGGER Toetjes.T_Ingredient 
   ON  Toetjes.Ingredient 
   AFTER INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
 IF (OLD.hoeveelheidPP <> NEW.hoeveelheidPP)
    BEGIN
      EXECUTE dbo.UpdateGerechtEnergie    @p_gerechtnaam=gerechtnaam
    END
END

Do I have to tell hem he is wrong? or do I have to replace the old an new statements?

Comment: `new` and `old` are definitely wrong if you're working with SQL Server. I *think* I've seen such things in other databases (MySQL maybe, or Oracle?).

Comment: Ok, the thing is, I for example want the trigger to be fired when the new value of Duurtussenstop is bigger then the old value when I use an update query, could you make a query out of that? Thx in advance :)

Comment: Thx! I just noticed that what you wrote was on the next page of my powerpoint... Thx anyway!

Answer (score 0):

It is a poor practice to call a proc in a trigger. It is especially poor if it is a proc that needs to run one record at at time.  SQL server triggers act on batches of records not one at a time. Suppose someone updated 100,000 records? What would happen to the trigger then? The way you are planning to write it, then only one record would affect the result and have the proc be run. You could put it ina cursor or while loop, but that would kill performance. Or you could ditch the proc and use a set-based solution.

You have to plan for those types of changes and test for them as well. You need to have set-based not record-looping processes in a trigger as slowness in a trigger can bring the entire sytem to a halt. Performance is critical. I once had to fix a curosr like that in a legacy database. It was taking over 40 minutes to insert 40,000 records (and I had a file to import that woudl be inserting millions of records). After rewrting to a set-based insert the same 40,000 records took only seconds to process.

When writing a triiger, you need to test both single record inserts and updates and multiple recor inserts and updates even if you think they never happen. Because sooner or later they will (no one is going to use the GUI to change the prices on 10,000 records one at a time for instance) and your trigger will bring a production system to a halt while it takes hours or even days to process the insert or update. Or alternatively, it won't properly process all the records but only one which will cause a data integrity issue.